# yast2 crashed at the moment of loading the install software module

Tags: x11, opensuse, rpm, zypper, yast

While trying to run a module from within yast in Tumbleweed openSUSE, the module crashed and it says in terminal

```
Run command: /sbin/yast2 sw_single &
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'YUIPluginException'
  what():  Couldn't load plug-in qt
YaST got signal 6 at file /usr/share/YaST2/modules/Wizard.rb:782
  sender PID: 7211
/sbin/yast2: line 440:  7211 中止                  (core dumped) $ybindir/y2base $module "$@" "$SELECTED_GUI" $Y2_GEOMETRY $Y2UI_ARGS
```

What this could　be ?

```
 zypper search libyui*
```

is:

```
S | 名前                     | 概要                                 | 種類      
--+--------------------------+--------------------------------------+-----------
  | libyui-devel             | Libyui header files                  | パッケージ
i | libyui-doc               | Libyui documentation                 | パッケージ
  | libyui-ncurses-devel     | Libyui-ncurses header files          | パッケージ
i | libyui-ncurses-doc       | Libyui-ncurses documentation         | パッケージ
  | libyui-ncurses-pkg-devel | Libyui-ncurses-pkg header files      | パッケージ
i | libyui-ncurses-pkg-doc   | Libyui-ncurses-pkg documentation     | パッケージ
i | libyui-ncurses-pkg7      | Libyui - yast2 package selector wi-> | パッケージ
i | libyui-ncurses7          | Libyui - Character Based User Inte-> | パッケージ
  | libyui-qt-devel          | Libyui-qt header files               | パッケージ
i | libyui-qt-doc            | Libyui-qt documentation              | パッケージ
  | libyui-qt-graph-devel    | Libyui-qt-graph header files         | パッケージ
i | libyui-qt-graph-doc      | Libyui-qt-graph documentation        | パッケージ
  | libyui-qt-graph7         | Libyui - Qt Graph Widget             | パッケージ
  | libyui-qt-pkg-devel      | Libyui-qt-pkg header files           | パッケージ
i | libyui-qt-pkg-doc        | Libyui-qt-pkg documentation          | パッケージ
i | libyui-qt-pkg7           | Libyui - Qt Package Selector         | パッケージ
i | libyui-qt7               | Libyui - Qt User Interface           | パッケージ
i | libyui7                  | Libyui - GUI-abstraction library     | パッケージ
```

Update, it seems to be related to a specific package/ パッケージ as cited [here](https://www.novell.com/support/kb/doc.php?id=7018387)
but making the process listed I still dont get the UI up.
Despite the page speaks about novell linux, and Im open Suse, there is no

`xorg-x11-libXrender-7.4-1.23.1`

but instead is

```
libXrender1-0.9.10-1.1.x86_64
```

So what would be needed? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Comment posted as answer by @PeterWegener : *"I had the same problem and an identical error message when starting yast2 from the command line -- and the fix worked for me as well. Thanks!"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem

```
 Run command: /sbin/yast2 sw_single &
 terminate called after throwing an instance of 'YUIPluginException'
  what():  Couldn't load plug-in qt
 /sbin/yast2: line 448:  4353 Aborted                 (core dumped) $ybindir/y2start $module "$@" "$SELECTED_GUI" $Y2_GEOMETRY $Y2UI_ARGS
```

---

```
 zypper se libyui
```

was

```
 S  | Name                            | Summary                                                     | Type   
 ---+---------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+--------
    | libyui-devel                    | Libyui header files                                         | package
    | libyui-doc                      | Libyui documentation                                        | package
    | libyui-ncurses-devel            | Libyui-ncurses header files                                 | package
    | libyui-ncurses-doc              | Libyui-ncurses documentation                                | package
    | libyui-ncurses-pkg-devel        | Libyui-ncurses-pkg header files                             | package
    | libyui-ncurses-pkg-doc          | Libyui-ncurses-pkg documentation                            | package
 i+ | libyui-ncurses-pkg7             | Libyui - yast2 package selector widget for the ncurses UI   | package
 i  | libyui-ncurses-pkg8             | Libyui - yast2 package selector widget for the ncurses UI   | package
 i+ | libyui-ncurses7                 | Libyui - Character Based User Interface                     | package
 i  | libyui-ncurses8                 | Libyui - Character Based User Interface                     | package
    | libyui-qt-devel                 | Libyui-qt header files                                      | package
    | libyui-qt-doc                   | Libyui-qt documentation                                     | package
    | libyui-qt-graph-devel           | Libyui-qt-graph header files                                | package
    | libyui-qt-graph-doc             | Libyui-qt-graph documentation                               | package
 i+ | libyui-qt-graph7                | Libyui - Qt Graph Widget                                    | package
    | libyui-qt-graph8                | Libyui - Qt Graph Widget                                    | package
    | libyui-qt-pkg-devel             | Libyui-qt-pkg header files                                  | package
    | libyui-qt-pkg-doc               | Libyui-qt-pkg documentation                                 | package
 i+ | libyui-qt-pkg7                  | Libyui - Qt Package Selector                                | package
    | libyui-qt-pkg8                  | Libyui - Qt Package Selector                                | package
 i+ | libyui-qt7                      | Libyui - Qt User Interface                                  | package
    | libyui-qt8                      | Libyui - Qt User Interface                                  | package
 i+ | libyui7                         | Libyui - GUI-abstraction library                            | package
 i  | libyui8                         | Libyui - GUI-abstraction library                            | package
    | ruby2.4-rubygem-libyui-rake     | Rake tasks providing basic work-flow for libyui development | package
    | ruby2.4-rubygem-libyui-rake-doc | RDoc documentation for libyui-rake                          | package
```

Fixed by

```
 zypper in libyui-qt8 libyui-qt-graph8 libyui-qt-pkg8
```

Answer (score 1):

I used an explicit command line option:

```
yast2 -gtk
```

to avoid the line 440 core dump. This is under openSUSE 42.2 for the yast2 binary of 2017-03-28.

Comment: `yast2 --gtk` is not supported anymore. `yast` or `yast2 --ncurses` will work.

Answer (score 1):

I had faced with the same problem and paid attention that my system only have  `libyui-qt7` but not `libyui-qt8`.

```
zypper se libyui-qt
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...

S  | Name              | Summary                       | Type   
---+-------------------+-------------------------------+--------
i+ | libyui-qt-graph7  | Libyui - Qt Graph Widget      | package
   | libyui-qt-graph8  | Libyui - Qt Graph Widget      | package
i+ | libyui-qt-pkg7    | Libyui - Qt Package Selector  | package
   | libyui-qt-pkg8    | Libyui - Qt Package Selector  | package
i+ | libyui-qt7        | Libyui - Qt User Interface    | package
   | libyui-qt8        | Libyui - Qt User Interface    | package
```

I have resolved it by installing `x86-64` version of the library `libyui-qt8` and now any module of the `Yast` starts successfully.

```
zypper in libyui-qt8
```